# Python Regular Expression and Matching

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a txt file containing the following information:

```
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\100.jpg 0
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\102.jpg 2
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\103 (2).jpg 0
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\105.jpg 0
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\104.jpg 0
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\106.jpg 0
```

I was trying to use regulator expression to check if the number between "ALL" and "\100" is the same as the last number. For example, the number between "ALL" and "\100" for the first line is 0 and it matches with 0. While the number between "ALL" and "\102" for the second line is 0 and it does not match with 2. I would like to detect those aren't matched and write them to a txt file.
I am new to Python and I don't know how to approach this. Could some give my any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Use 2 regexes. One to extract value from the middle of the path and one for the last number. check if same and continue your logic

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex pattern:

```regex
^C:\\.*\\(\d+)\\\d+.*\.\w+ \1$
```

This would only match file paths such that the number in the last path element matches the number at the end of the input.  Here is a Python script:

```py
files = ['C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\100.jpg 0', 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\102.jpg 2', 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\103 (2).jpg 0', 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\105.jpg 0', 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\104.jpg 0', 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\106.jpg 0']
keep = [f for f in files if re.search(r'^C:\\.*\\(\d+)\\\d+.*\.\w+ \1$', f)]
print(keep)
```

This prints:

```
['C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\100.jpg 0', 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\103 (2).jpg 0',
 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\105.jpg 0', 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\104.jpg 0',
 'C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\106.jpg 0']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?P<name>...)` to name a group in your regex match and then `(?P=name)` to match that group with the same name

```
C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\(?P<num>\d)\\.*?\.jpg (?P=num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using pandas becuase it's clean

```
import pandas as pd
text = '''C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\100.jpg 0
C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\102.jpg 2
C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\103 (2).jpg 0
C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\105.jpg 0
C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\104.jpg 0
C:\\temp\\ccA03-All\\0\\106.jpg 0'''
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':text.splitlines()})
```

table:

```
    data
0   C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\100.jpg 0
1   C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\102.jpg 2
2   C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\103 (2).jpg 0
3   C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\105.jpg 0
4   C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\104.jpg 0
5   C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\106.jpg 0
```

extraction:

```
df.data.str.extract('All\\\(\d+).*\s(\d+)')
```

result:

```
    0   1
0   0   0
1   0   2
2   0   0
3   0   0
4   0   0
5   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
files=r"""C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\100.jpg 0
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\102.jpg 2
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\103 (2).jpg 0
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\105.jpg 0
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\104.jpg 0
C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\106.jpg 0"""
files=files.split("\n")
f=open("error.txt",'w',encoding="utf8")
for file in files:
    aa=re.search(r".*All\\(.*?)\\",file).group(1)
    bb=re.search(r" ([0-9]+)",file).group(1)
    if int(aa)!=int(bb):
        f.write(file)
f.close()
```

.group(1) returns what is inside () so
**aa** returns the fisrt number C:\temp\ccA03-All\ **0** \100.jpg 0
and **bb** the second number as string  C:\temp\ccA03-All\0\100.jpg **0**